# How to sanitize CSV input with one-space strings?

Tags: python, csv, python-3.x

So here's the situation:

- I'm reading CSV files where the majority of the time, empty cells are just empty strings. Some files that come in the same set, for whatever reason, have one-space strings in 'empty cells' instead of empty strings.
- I'm using `csv`'s DictReader to read from these files (with ',' as the delimiter) and it will automatically convert empty strings to `None` type values prior to my inserting them into a PostgreSQL db.
- I tried registering a Dialect object that set `skipinitialspace=True`, but now they remain empty strings which, unlike `None`, is still an invalid input for SQL table columns that I have set to integer values (so I'm guessing DictReader converts empty strings to `None` prior to removing the leading whitespace).

How can I get around this?

Disclaimer: I could reach a solution by just converting all the one-space-strings to `None` types myself after I have read the values and have the row's dict from DictReader, but it seems clunky and I'd prefer a more elegant solution if possible.

**Example normal csv**

```
foo_id,foo_text,foo_value
1,'hello',4
3,,2
```

**Example problem csv**

```
bar_id,bar_text,bar_value
1,'hello',4
3, ,2
```

**Example csv read script**

```
with open('foo.txt') as csv_file:
    csv.register_dialect('example_dialect', delimiter=',', skipinitialspace=True)
    gtfsreader = DictReader(csv_file, dialect='example_dialect')
    for row in gtfsreader:
        print(row)
```

Comment: It would probably help if you post the relevant parts of the code you're using. A reasonably small *runnable* example is generally requested so a section of the csv file would be handy as well.

Comment: Good tip, added some code

Comment: I think the best option is your clunky one of replacing the `" "` values with `None` manually. If you like you could create a subclass of `csv.Reader` which handles this behind the scenes but you'll be doing the same thing whether you hide it or not. I don't really think this advice is worth putting in an answer. Hopefully someone else can help more!

Answer (score 0):

Never figured out a way to deal configure DictReader to do this for me, but in the meantime, I did wind up just manually sanitizing each row with this helper function:

```
def __sanitize__(row):
  for key, value in row.items():
    if value in ('', ' '):
      row[key] = None
  return row
```

Still hope someone can come along with a sexier answer!